# Given the equation $P(x) = x^4 + bx^2 + c$ and the points $(3,25)$ and $(1,9).$ How to find $b$ and $c$ such that it passes through the points?

Tags: polynomials

By using Desmos I've found that the values of $\;b = -8\;$ and $\;c = 16,\;$ but that doesn't really help me understand how to get those numbers.

Answer and why I got it wrong:

I've evaluated:

$ 9 = 1^4 + b\cdot1^2 + c \implies b = 8 - c \implies c = 8 - b$

and

$ 25 = 3^4 + b\cdot3^2 + c \implies c = -56 - 9b $

The part which I forgot to do was to substitute the equations into each other and **not** the original equation.  KM101 provides a more complete breakdown.

$ c = -56 - 9(8 - c) \implies c = 16$

$ -9b - 56 = 8 - b \implies b = -8$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Two unknowns, two equations!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $P(u)-P(v)=u^4-v^4+b(u^2-v^2)$.  From $25-9=81-1+b(9-1)$  you’ll find $b=-8$. Now exploit $P(1)=9$, that is $1-8+c=9$ to find $c=16$.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute the $(x,y)$ pairs in to get a system of linear equations, which may be easily solved:
$$1^4+1^2b+c=9\qquad3^4+3^2b+c=25$$
$$b+c=8\qquad 9b+c=-56$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$25=3^4+b3^2+c \implies 9b+c=-56$$

$$9=1^4+b1^2+c \implies b+c=8$$

Answer (score 0):

Here’s our function.
$$f(x) = x^4+bx^2+c$$
We’re given two points.
$$A: (1, 9)$$
$$B: (3, 25)$$
For point $A$,  substitute $x$ and $y$ with $1$ and $9$, respectively. $$9 = 1^4+b(1)^2+c$$
$$9 = 1+b+c \implies \boxed{b+c = 8}$$
For point $B$, substitute $x$ and $y$ with $3$ and $25$, respectively.
$$25 = 3^4+b(3)^2+c$$
$$25 = 81+9b+c \implies \boxed{9b+c = -56}$$
Now, use elimination to solve for $b$ and $c$.
$$9b+c-(b+c)= -56-8$$
$$9b+c-b-c = -56-9 \implies 8b = -64$$
$$\boxed{b = -8}$$
Now, plug in $b = -8$ in either of the two equations to get $c$.
$$9(-8)+c = -56$$
$$-72+c = -56 \implies \boxed{c = 16}$$
So, the final quartic equation containing these two points is $f(x) = x^4-8x^2+16$.